# How can i use "of" in redux-observable

Tags: reactjs, redux-observable

I'm new to Redux-Observable. So, I apply redux-observable in my project, and i want to dispatch action by redux-observable so i used "of" (like Observable.of() in RXJS version before). But the reponse that i received is "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions". Is there a wrong with my set up epic middleware or code?

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { createEpicMiddleware } from 'redux-observable';
import { rootEpic } from './epics';
import reducers from './reducers';

const epicMiddleWare = createEpicMiddleware();
const configureStore = () => {
  const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(epicMiddleWare),
      window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : (f) => { return f; },
    ),
  );

  epicMiddleWare.run(rootEpic);

  return store;
};

export default configureStore;
```

**epic.js**

```
export const fetchNavigationEpic = (action$) => {
  return action$
    .ofType(actionTypes.FETCH_NAVIGATION_LIST)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(() => {
        return from(CreateService(SettingService).getAll())
          .pipe(
            map((response) => {
              if (response.status === 200) {
                return of(fetchNavigationSuccess(response));
              }

              return fetchNavigationFailed(response);
            }),
          );
      }),
    );
};
```

**action.js**

```
export const fetchNavigation = { type: actionTypes.FETCH_NAVIGATION_LIST };
export const fetchNavigationSuccess = (payload) => {
  return { type: actionTypes.FETCH_NAVIGATION_LIST_SUCCESS, payload };
};
export const fetchNavigationFailed = (payload) => {
  return { type: actionTypes.FETCH_NAVIGATION_LIST_FAILED, payload };
};
```

Library information:
 "redux-observable": "^1.0.0", 
 "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
 "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're returning a stream not an action.

If you're return an observable (of(yourAction)), you need to flatten that using `mergeMap`

If you're return the action, then you can use `map` instead of `mergeMap`

So it's either

```
export const fetchNavigationEpic = (action$) => {
  return action$
    .ofType(actionTypes.FETCH_NAVIGATION_LIST)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(() => {
        return from(CreateService(SettingService).getAll())
          .pipe(
            mergeMap((response) => {
              if (response.status === 200) {
                return of(fetchNavigationSuccess(response));
              }

              return of(fetchNavigationFailed(response));
            }),
          );
      }),
    );
};
```

Or

```
export const fetchNavigationEpic = (action$) => {
      return action$
        .ofType(actionTypes.FETCH_NAVIGATION_LIST)
        .pipe(
          mergeMap(() => {
            return from(CreateService(SettingService).getAll())
              .pipe(
                map((response) => {
                  if (response.status === 200) {
                    return fetchNavigationSuccess(response);
                  }

                  return fetchNavigationFailed(response);
                }),
              );
          }),
        );
    };
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Anas. It worked for me. You saved me.